# Huge number of classes with Multinominal Naive Bayes (scikit-learn)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

Whenever I start having a bigger number of classes (1000 and more) MultinominalNB gets super slow and takes Gigabytes of RAM. The same is true for all the scikit learn classification algorithms that support .partial_fit() (SGDClassifier, Perceptron).
When working with convolutional neural networks 10000 classes are no problem. But when I want to train MultinominalNB on the same data my 12GB of RAM are not enough and it is very very slow.
From my understanding of Naive Bayes, even with a lot of classes, it should be a lot faster.
Might this be a problem of the scikit-learn implementation (maybe of the .partial_fit() function) ? How can I train MultinominalNB/SGDClassifier/Perceptron on 10000+ classes (batchwise)?

Comment: Give us some more information. What is the shape of your training data? How many samples and how many features do you have?

Comment: The training data is around 5 Mio text documents. I am using HashingVectorizer wit number of features = 2^18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer without much information:

- The MultinomialNB fits an *independent model* to each of the classes, thus, if you have `C=10000+` classes it will fit `C=10000+` models and therefore, only the model parameters will be `[n_classes x n_features]`, which is quite a lot of memory if `n_features` is large.
- The SGDClassifier of scikits-learn uses OVA (one-versus-all) strategy to train a multiclass model (as the SGDC is not inherently multiclass) and therefore, another `C=10000+` models need to be trained.
- And Perceptron, from the documentation of scikits-learn:

> Perceptron and SGDClassifier share the same underlying implementation. In fact, Perceptron() is equivalent to SGDClassifier(loss=”perceptron”, eta0=1, learning_rate=”constant”, penalty=None).

So, all the 3 classifiers you mention don't work well with high number of classes, as an independent model needs to be trained for each of the classes. I would recommend you to try something that inherently support multiclass classification, such as [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far. Unfortunately RandomForestClassifier can not be trained on batches (does not have the .partial_fit() method). As the training data is 5 Mio samples I have to do batchwise training. How could I approach that?

Comment: @jasmok You can try with [`LogisticRegression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression) setting `multiclass='multinomial'` (rather than the default `ovr` which stands for `one-versus-rest`, the same as `one-versus-all`). For more info: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html . However expect long training time and memory requeriments for all that data you have.

Comment: But LogisticRegression does not support batch training. So I will have to fit all data into memory. That will not work for 5 Mio samples. SGDRegressor would support batch training, but it does not have the multinomial option.

Comment: @jasmok then `SGDClassifier` with `loss='log'` (online logistic regression) will be your best option. However, will still take long to train it.

Comment: @jasmok your data is too big, u should expect long training times and huge memory requeriments.

Comment: @jasmok I you want a bit more speed, you can try to have a look at Theano (imeplements vectorized operations in GPU). Find [here](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html) an example of logistic regression with stochastic gradient descent.